# using localizable property method versus ResXResourceSet method

Tags: .net, localization, globalization

Can anyone tell me what is more appropriate for different types of .net applications?

Answer (score 1):

The "Localizable" property* on a Windows Form tells Windows to create and use a .resx resource file for the string properties of the controls on the form. .NET will load the appropriate resource file depending on your current UI culture.

`ResXResourceSet`, detailed on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourceset.aspx), makes it easy to programmatically read the same .resx resource file.

So in a nutshell they're really the same thing: one is an automatic mechanism for Windows Forms to use resource files, and one is for program access. Typically a Windows Forms application would use the Localizable property for fixed UI elements and the ResXResourceSet to access additional properties for prompts, variable text and whatnot.

*that makes me chuckle, as "Localizable" should be "Localisable" in British English